# -webkit-tap-highlight-color: опасно использовать или нет?

Tags: css, css3, webkit

Недавно узнала про CSS-свойство -webkit-tap-highlight-color, которое позволяет убрать голубоватый фон при тапе на элемент во многих браузерах. Однако MDN предупреждает, что данное свойство нестандартное и не рекомендует его использовать. Да и на многих крупных сайтах фон при тапе присутствует.

Использовали ли вы это свойство и были ли какие-то проблемы с ним? Рекомендуете им пользоваться или пока не стоит?

Answer (score 2):

Лично моё мнение:

> Данное свойство работает только в версиях WebKit на мобильных
>   платформах (например, браузерах Chrome и Safari на устройствах с iOS
>   версии 1.1.1 и выше), и не совместимо с другими браузерами.

Я бы не стал его использовать. Для меня (как пользователя) удобнее, когда я вижу, на что конкретно приземлился мой палец на экране... К тому же да, оно далеко не везде поддерживается. Смысла не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте -webkit-tap-highlight-color, только с пониманием.

Как здесь верно было сказано, юзер-френдли интерфейс должен реагировать на действия пользователя. Поэтому в качестве подстраховки **для недоделанного дизайна** браузер подсвечивает нажатую ссылку. Если же вы вешаете какое-то свойство (*реакцию*) на a:active, то надо добавить и свойство -webkit-tap-highlight-color с параметром transparent, т.к. вы уже позаботились о визуализации нажатия. Проблем никаких не будет, красота только будет.