# Кросбраузерность и совместимость -webkit-tap-highlight-color

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность, совместимость

Коллеги, не могу найти точную информацию будет ли работать на сегодняшний день свойство -webkit-tap-highlight-color во всех браузерах одинаково.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет прояснить.

Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [-webkit-tap-highlight-color: опасно использовать или нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941831/webkit-tap-highlight-color-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: @BlackStar1991 видел этот вопрос. Не понимаю как быть в таком случае, если я хочу отказаться от этой подсветки. Какой прием использовать?

Comment: никому не интересно заниматься поддержкой данного свойства. Ничего не изменилось с того времени.  https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Comment: @BlackStar1991 может быть есть какое-то решение? Прием? Подойдут даже костыли.